# merging two maps/list for json body in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know if my question will be clear but here's my question.

i have here a print of a list as you can see below.
[image]

as you can see, those in the red border is a duplicate. while I plan that the yellow borders be combined in a single list since they have a duplicate header (red border).

Result list should look something like this (combined):

`[2022-177916, Installing Cut-Out, WEXEC, 2022-03-22 00:37:26.000Z, CP, LEXT, , , 212618, [2034132, CUT-OUTS, HT FUSE, 100A, 36KV, 170KV BIL, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -88.0, , UNIT, false, false, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2035103, FUSELINK, 3K, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -10.0, , PC, false, false, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]`

Here, yellow bordered data are now in a single list. then the duplicate (red border) was combined.

Hope someone could guide me in the right direction. im stuck :(

Edit:

More info on the codes below.

`List<ChildrenCreateMRO> mroTempChildrenCreateSend = []; //this is the list i declared`

I made a listview.builder wherein each item has a checkbox. if the user taps the checkbox, then I add some data to the list by using `mroTempChildrenCreateSend.add()`

so the list grows but i have several duplicates.
the sample output above was from two checked checkboxes.

Comment: Please add the current lists to the question.

Comment: In order to help you with your problem, we need to know how that data is generated, and how it is normalized (merged), so we can determine a suitable algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spread operator.
For example: `final newList = [...list1, ...list2, ...list3];`
list1 is the name of one of the lists, and so on. the ... is the spread operator, dropping all of the contents into the new list.
Please update your question with the code so I can better answer the question.

Comment: hello! i only have 1 list for this. i only used list1.add() to add data to the list. see edit above.

Comment: Please add the code for the checkbox tap and any code that manages state.

Comment: hey man, is it okay if i paste the whole code? https://justpaste.it/6b6d1. just check the checkbox widget part. thanks! @Jacob Miller